# Why isn't my try except catching if you put a string into the argument of score?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0.
#If the score is out of range print an error.
#If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0, print a grade using the following table:
#Score Grade >=0.9 A >=0.8 B >=0.7 C >=0.6 D <0.6 F

def computegrade(score):
    try:
        score1 = float(score)
        if score1 <= 1.0 and score1 >= 0.9:        
            grade = "A"
        elif score1 < 0.9 and score1 >= 0.8:
            grade = "B"
        elif score1 < 0.8 and score1 >= 0.7:
            grade = "C"
        elif score1 < 0.7 and score1 >= 0.6:
            grade = "D"
        elif score1 < 0.6 and score1 > 0:
            grade = "F"
        else:
            grade = "ERROR: You did not enter a number or you entered a number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0!"
        print(grade) 
    except:
        print("ERROR: You did not enter a number or you entered a number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0!")
```

Everything seems to work as expected whether I enter an integer outside the range of 0.0 and 1.0 or enter within that range.  I created a try except to catch if the user inputs a string for score.  But it doesn't seem to catch it and I can't figure out why.

Comment: So how are you calling it?

Comment: And what's the output?

Comment: You can chain conditions like this: `0.9 <= score1 <= 1.0`

Comment: I can't reproduce. It works for me. But you do need to change you except clause to catch a `ValueError` specifically, instead of any exception.

Comment: You have a bare `except`, which will catch anything. That is bad practice. But aside from that, what is the input string, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Is your string something like `"0.8"`?

Comment: I have been trying this:

Comment: >>> computegrade(dragoon)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    computegrade(dragoon)
NameError: name 'dragoon' is not defined
>>> computegrade("dragoon")
>>>

Comment: What would be good practice than juanpa.arrivillaga?  I'm still a beginner with Python.  That's what the book I'm reading suggested but I'm only in chapter 4 so maybe it will suggest better form later on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked fine. Make sure the input is a string that can't be converted to float and you should be fine.

```
def computegrade(score):
    try:
        score1 = float(score)
        if score1 <= 1.0 and score1 >= 0.9:
            grade = "A"
        elif score1 < 0.9 and score1 >= 0.8:
            grade = "B"
        elif score1 < 0.8 and score1 >= 0.7:
            grade = "C"
        elif score1 < 0.7 and score1 >= 0.6:
            grade = "D"
        elif score1 < 0.6 and score1 > 0:
            grade = "F"
        else:
            grade = "ERROR: You did not enter a number or you entered a     number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0!"
        print(grade)
    except:
        print("ERROR: You did not enter a number or you entered a number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0!")
computegrade("fire")
```

Output:

```
ERROR: You did not enter a number or you entered a number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0!
```

Comment: I must not be entering it in correctly then.  Here is what I am trying:

Comment: >>> computegrade(dragoon)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    computegrade(dragoon)
NameError: name 'dragoon' is not defined
>>> computegrade("dragoon")
>>>

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Cary,  The function is called computegrade and in parenthesis are the items I was trying.  So in the above example I ran the function with the word dragoon and then with quotes "dragoon". Sorry if that was unclear, I'm still pretty new at explaining/learning things.

Comment: Sorry I should have figured that out. what was the output from compute grade("dragoon")?

Comment: Cary, No worries.  There was no output, it excepted the variable and didn't print the catch, my try statement to say you need to enter output in certain format.

Comment: There was no output from the second call, `computegrade("dragoon")`?